# É possível mudar o zoom do navegador com código?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, zoom

Existe alguma forma de mudar o zoom do navegador com `JavaScript`?

Ao carregar o `script` gostaria de mudar o zoom do navegador para 100%, pode ser usando qualquer framework *(Angular, jQuery)*.

Ficaria muito agradecido se pudessem ajudar.

Comment: Tenho um código que funciona apenas no IE eno Chrome, haha! Mesmo que nada, pode ser ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veja [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093570/force-page-zoom-at-100-with-js) resposta (inglês).

Em suma é possível usar:

```
document.body.style.zoom = 1.0
```

Mas esta propriedade [não é padrão para todos os browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom).

Ao invés disso use tranforms:

```
var scale = 'scale(1)';
document.body.style.webkitTransform =  scale;    // Chrome, Opera, Safari
document.body.style.msTransform =   scale;       // IE 9
document.body.style.transform = scale;     // Geral
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.body.style.zoom = "200%"
```

```html
<p>Olá, mundo!</p>
```

Eu testei esse código no IE e CHROME. Porém acredito que ele seja Cross-Browser.